# HTML 5 Dialog element overlapping google captcha

Tags: html, dialog, captcha

I have an issue with captcha and HTML5 dialog element, my dialog box is overlapping captcha images[image]

I have changed z-index of my dilogbox to 0, but still its overlapping. I am using dialog-polyfill. How I can fix this issue?

This issue is happening in Mac Google Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)

Please see the jsfiddle link here:

```
<div class="container">
    <dialog class="auth">
    <div id="recaptcha"></div>
    </dialog>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a8793aop/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue, I was using showModal() instead of show() to display the dialogbox. showModal() will add the dialogbox to "top layer". The z-index property has no effect in the top layer.
[HTML5 top layer](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#top-layer)